# Log execution of Quartz.Net jobs in a custom format

Tags: c#, asp.net, service, quartz.net

I am using [Quartz.Net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) as a Windows Service for a scheduling system. The built in logging system is using the **Common.Logging framework** but only logs "*some information during initialization, and then only messages about serious problems while Jobs are executing*" (see [this link](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/configuration-resource-usage-and-scheduler-factory.html) - bottom).

In order to log the actual history execution of my jobs I succesfully configured the `LoggingJobHistoryPlugin` by adding this line in the `quartz.config` file of the service:

```
quartz.plugin.triggHistory.type = Quartz.Plugin.History.LoggingJobHistoryPlugin
```

At this point, the execution logging works fine (in all appenders - SQL database, file, etc..). You can see an excerpt here:

```
426 2014-11-07 10:30:05.997 ServerScheduler_Worker-7    INFO    Quartz.Plugin.History.LoggingJobHistoryPlugin.JobWasExecuted(c:\Work\OpenSource\quartznet\src\Quartz\Plugin\History\LoggingJobHistoryPlugin.cs:432) Job Admin.Auto Sync execution complete at 08:30:05 11/07/2014 and reports: 
425 2014-11-07 10:30:00.070 ServerScheduler_Worker-7    INFO    Quartz.Plugin.History.LoggingJobHistoryPlugin.JobToBeExecuted(c:\Work\OpenSource\quartznet\src\Quartz\Plugin\History\LoggingJobHistoryPlugin.cs:383)    Job Admin.Auto Sync fired (by trigger admin.Admin) at: 08:30:00 11/07/2014
```

What I am trying to achieve is to change the default logging format as described [here](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/1.0/html/html/233af0b1-771e-fc0b-9b27-dacc27d08ba5.htm). What I tried is to set these lines in the `quartz.config` file:

```
quartz.plugin.triggHistory.jobToBeFiredMessage = *** Job {1}.{0} fired (by trigger {4}.{3}) at: {2, date, HH:mm:ss MM/dd/yyyy}
quartz.plugin.triggHistory.jobSuccessMessage = *** Job {1}.{0} execution complete at {2, date, HH:mm:ss MM/dd/yyyy} and reports: {8}
quartz.plugin.triggHistory.jobFailedMessage = *** Job {1}.{0} execution failed at {2, date, HH:mm:ss MM/dd/yyyy} and reports: {8}
```

But after I add these lines I get the following errors in the logs:

```
384 2014-11-07 10:24:00.037 ServerScheduler_Worker-3    ERROR   Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.NotifySchedulerListenersError(c:\Work\OpenSource\quartznet\src\Quartz\Core\QuartzScheduler.cs:1877) Unable to notify JobListener(s) of Job to be executed: (Job will NOT be executed!). trigger= Test.Tr5 job= Test.1 minute    
383 2014-11-07 10:23:00.027 ServerScheduler_Worker-2    ERROR   Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.NotifySchedulerListenersError(c:\Work\OpenSource\quartznet\src\Quartz\Core\QuartzScheduler.cs:1877) Unable to notify JobListener(s) of Job to be executed: (Job will NOT be executed!). trigger= Test.Tr5 job= Test.1 minute    
382 2014-11-07 10:22:00.143 ServerScheduler_Worker-1    ERROR   Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.NotifySchedulerListenersError(c:\Work\OpenSource\quartznet\src\Quartz\Core\QuartzScheduler.cs:1877) Unable to notify JobListener(s) of Job to be executed: (Job will NOT be executed!). trigger= Test.Tr5 job= Test.1 minute
```

Any iddea how can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API documentation was unfortunately wrong, I've now corrected it now in the [more up-to-date 2.0 documentation](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/html/233af0b1-771e-fc0b-9b27-dacc27d08ba5.htm). The correct format for date is the standard .NET string formatting:

```
quartz.plugin.triggHistory.jobToBeFiredMessage = *** Job {1}.{0} fired (by trigger {4}.{3}) at: {2:HH:mm:ss MM/dd/yyyy}
quartz.plugin.triggHistory.jobSuccessMessage = *** Job {1}.{0} execution complete at {2:HH:mm:ss MM/dd/yyyy} and reports: {8}
quartz.plugin.triggHistory.jobFailedMessage = *** Job {1}.{0} execution failed at {2:HH:mm:ss MM/dd/yyyy} and reports: {8}
```

Comment: I have another question about this: how can I get the actual error message when logging `JobFailedMessage`? I can only get the `details` using `{8}`, but this doesn't help at all. For example, for a `(401) Unauthorized` exception, all I can log is `Job threw an unhandled exception.`, not the actual error message.

Comment: Generally as jobs should throw a JobExecutionException, I'd try to wrap you job main execution with try-catch and throw as JobExecutionException with the original exception's message. Otherwise for non-JobExecutionExceptions Quartz will wrap them and the original error is only available as InnerException.